# If no records found, use another query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(sub.value) AS DURATION
FROM
    (SELECT 
        TENANT_SETTING_VALUE AS VALUE
    FROM
        MST_SITE_PREFERENCES
    WHERE
        `TENANT_ID` = '{0559cdcb-c63b-4c81-be91-b78Tenant1000' 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
        DEFAULT_SETTING
    FROM
        `GLO_SITE_PREFERENCES` AS VALUE
    WHERE
        `SETTING_ID` = 'ESTIMATED_SAVINGS_DURATION_IN_MONTHS') sub;
```

The above query returns value like

```
130,50
```

- The first query`(from MST_SITE_PREFERENCES)` is on the master table
- The second query `(GLO_SITE_PREFERENCES)` is on the global table.

Requirement here is if no matches found for second query, it should return the first value - 130. If found, it should return the value 50. So all the time the query should return only one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this version does what you want (although I am unclear on which has precedence, the first or second query).

```
select value
from ((select TENANT_SETTING_VALUE as value, 1 as which
       from MST_SITE_PREFERENCES
       where `TENANT_ID` = '{0559cdcb-c63b-4c81-be91-b78Tenant1000'
      ) union all
      (select DEFAULT_SETTING, 2 as which
       from `GLO_SITE_PREFERENCES` AS VALUE
       where `SETTING_ID` = 'ESTIMATED_SAVINGS_DURATION_IN_MONTHS'
      ) 
     ) t
order by which
limit 1;
```

If the precedence is wrong, just switch the values on `which`.

You could also express this as:

```
select TENANT_SETTING_VALUE as value, 1 as which
from MST_SITE_PREFERENCES
where `TENANT_ID` = '{0559cdcb-c63b-4c81-be91-b78Tenant1000'
union all
select DEFAULT_SETTING, 2 as which
from `GLO_SITE_PREFERENCES` AS VALUE
where `SETTING_ID` = 'ESTIMATED_SAVINGS_DURATION_IN_MONTHS' and
       not exists (select TENANT_SETTING_VALUE as value, 1 as which
                   from MST_SITE_PREFERENCES
                   where `TENANT_ID` = '{0559cdcb-c63b-4c81-be91-b78Tenant1000'
                  );
```

Similarly here, if the precedence is wrong, the subqueries need to be rearranged.

Comment: The first query does the job.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sub.value) AS DURATION
FROM
( case 
  when
  ((SELECT count(TENANT_SETTING_VALUE) AS VALUE 
      FROM MST_SITE_PREFERENCES 
    WHERE `TENANT_ID` = '{0559cdcb-c63b-4c81-be91-b78Tenant1000')>0)
  then
    SELECT TENANT_SETTING_VALUE AS VALUE 
      FROM MST_SITE_PREFERENCES 
    WHERE `TENANT_ID` = '{0559cdcb-c63b-4c81-be91-b78Tenant1000')
  when
  ((SELECT count(DEFAULT_SETTING) AS VALUE
    FROM `GLO_SITE_PREFERENCES` 
     WHERE `SETTING_ID`='ESTIMATED_SAVINGS_DURATION_IN_MONTHS')>0)
   then
    SELECT DEFAULT_SETTING AS VALUE
    FROM `GLO_SITE_PREFERENCES` 
     WHERE `SETTING_ID`='ESTIMATED_SAVINGS_DURATION_IN_MONTHS'
) sub;
```

This works provided your `subquery returns just 1 row`